# How to get new instance of the my Application class per each unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have an Android app that has `MyApplication` class that inherits from `Application`.

I've created few unit tests that run with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`. If I run each test separately they all pass. If I run them together - first one passes and then (some of the) others fail.

The problem is that it seems that only one instance of the `MyApplication` is created and then it is preserved and used for all test which causes the fails because there is a state in the `MyApplication` which MUST be initialized only once.

Is there a way to run the unit tests (androidTest) so application is restarted for each test? I don't care if it will be slow (e.g. app will have to be reinstalled each time) I just want tests to run independently of one another.

Actual code from the unit test looks like (as requested by @Zinc):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class AutoLogin_ActMainTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ActMain> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<ActMain>(
            ActMain.class) {


        @Override
        protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
            super.beforeActivityLaunched();

            MyTestApp app = (MyTestApp) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
            DependencyInjector.reset();
            app.reset();


            FakeUnitDaggerModule fudm = new FakeUnitDaggerModule();

            Session session = new SessionImpl(new TimeProviderImpl());
            fudm.setResMain(new ResMainTest(session));

            FakeAppPrefs appPrefs = new FakeAppPrefs();
            FakeLoginPrefs loginPrefs = new FakeLoginPrefs();
            CurrentUserHolder currentUserHolder = new CurrentUserHolder();

            FakeComponent inj = DaggerFakeComponent.builder().
                    fakeMyAppDaggerModule(new FakeMyAppDaggerModule(app, appPrefs, loginPrefs, currentUserHolder)).
                    appInfoDaggerModule(new AppInfoDaggerModule("1")).
                    fakeSessionDaggerModule(new FakeSessionDaggerModule(session)).
                    fakeExchangeDaggerModule(new FakeExchangeDaggerModule("https://test.com")).
                    fakeUnitDaggerModule(fudm).
                    build();

            DependencyInjector.init(inj);
            DependencyInjector.getInstance().inject(app);


            app.onStart();
        }
    };


    @Test
    public void testAutoLogin() {
        ElapsedTimeIdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(500);
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);
        idlingResource.startWaiting();

        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.tv_logged_in_as)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Zinc Added code from one of the tests

Comment: why you are not using degger ?

Comment: @Saveen degger? What do you mean?

Comment: @Ognyan dagger is use for dependency injections  take a look from here http://square.github.io/dagger/

Comment: This state, is it publicly exposed and can it be altered externally?

Comment: NVM, I just saw the `reset` that you've described in the bounty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is that it seems that only one instance of the MyApplication is created and then it is preserved and used for all test which causes the fails because there is a state in the MyApplication which MUST be initialized only once.

IMHO, that's a bug in the app, which should be fixed. `Application` is an unsuitable location for much true business logic (though it is fine for initializing your crash-reporter library, `StrictMode`, etc.). Everything else should be testable individually, either directly, via mocks, via dependency injection, etc.

That being said, sometimes the problem isn't in code that you control, but rather code from libraries or the framework.

> Is there a way to run the unit tests (androidTest) so application is restarted for each test?

Nowadays, yes, though there wasn't at the time this question was asked. The [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator) (ATO) does a better job of isolating each test, at a cost of test execution speed.

Comment: The only code in the app class is the initialization of the dependency injector (Dagger 2). This ATO looks like exactly what I am looking for but I have this concern: in its docs it is stated: "Therefore, if your tests share app state, **most** of that shared state is removed from your device's CPU or memory after each test". The word "most" is the concern - do you know what is NOT removed, or at least where I can find the code of the ATO in order to look at it by myself?

Comment: @Ognyan: "do you have idea what is NOT removed" -- when I put the ATO through its paces, it seemed to create fresh processes for each test. I have no idea what that portion of the docs is referring to. "where I can find the code of the ATO in order to look at it by myself?" -- not off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: If anyone is interested: one thing that is not removed are files created in a public dir (i.e. `getExternalFilesDir()`). Still not able to test if files in private dir are preserved but if that is the case you have to pay extra attention to hidden file creation like http caches for example. Another pitfall might be that "external" devices like camera, GPS, etc that might need manual reset between each of the tests.

Comment: Another drawback of the ATO is that so far I am unable to find a way to mark which tests need new instance of `Instrumentation` and which not, thus forcing me to make all-or-nothing choice (which, from my point of view, renders ATO almost unusable - I need it for less than 5% of the tests. For a medium sized app it will mean that executing all tests in ATO will take very long amount of time, not to mention that the CI server might get overloaded).

Answer (score 2):

You need to refactor your app so that whatever code is controlling state is not bound to the application class but in another object. Then you can reset that piece or mock it out without caring about the persistence of the application class. Preferably this is done using some form dependency injection.

Comment: Another object is not really a solution because it is just moving the problem from the Application to that object (I've played a lot with the problem and different solutions including DI). I know that Google recommends "There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality". Currently I am reseting the Application state in the beginning of each test, but this is a hack. I was hoping that there is genuine way to tell the tests to run with new Application each time. Something like gradle setting or even SDK call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your question. But you can use ApplicationTestCase. Some thing like:

```
public class MyApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<MyTestApp> {
    public void test1() {
        createApplication();

        ... test here ...

        terminateApplication();
    }

    public void test2() {
        createApplication();

        ... test here ...

        terminateApplication();
    }
}
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.html

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot use `ApplicationTestCase`, I need the `beforeActivityLaunched()` of the Rule. Also `ApplicationTestCase` is deprecated...

Comment: **ApplicationTestCase** is not deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class TestApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Sdk.terminate(); - If you specify TestApplication as an 
    //                    application class in AndroidManifest, 
    //                    you'll have to uncomment this(due to issue with test runner)
    Sdk.initialize();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
    Sdk.terminate();
}
}
```

**Sdk class**

```
    public class Sdk {

private static Sdk sInstance;
private void Sdk(){
}

public static Sdk getInstance() throws RuntimeException {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public static void terminate() {
    sInstance = null;
}

public static void initialize() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new Sdk();
        //save some information according to what is on the default configurations
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method was already initialized");
    }
}}
```

Tests:

```
    public class MyApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<TestApplication> {

public MyApplicationTest() {
    super(TestApplication.class);
}

public void testMultiplicationTests() {
    createApplication();

    int answer = 42;
    assertEquals(42, answer);

    terminateApplication();
}


public void testDefaultSettings() {
    createApplication();

    assertNotNull(Sdk.getInstance());

    terminateApplication();
}}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment `ApplicationTestCase` is deprecated and I really need to use the new `ActivityTestRule`. Otherwise solution seem to do the trick (I am using now similar approach).